# Invalid File path even though I have checked it in java

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am using `java.net.DatagramPacket` to trans file. I have some code below

```
public void sendFile(InetAddress clientHost,  int clientPort, String fileName) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "e:\\uri\\" + fileName;
    System.out.println(filePath);
    FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(filePath);
}
```

I have a folder `uri` in and do create `file.txt` first. While debuging this, this is what shows up in console:

```
e:\uri\file.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Invalid file path
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:133)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at MyFileServerSocket.sendFile(MyFileServerSocket.java:19)
    at FiletransServer.main(FiletransServer.java:22)
```

I found something more interesting that i can see the value of `fileName` in eclipse and it's strange.[image]
There is extra quotation marks in there and the string printed in the console is normal. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `fileName` you've passed into `sendFile(...)` has illegal characters. Please check it thoroughly and you should try hardcode `filePath` something like this and try once again:

```
public void sendFile(InetAddress clientHost,  int clientPort, String fileName) throws IOException {
    // Hardcode file.txt
    String filePath = "e:\\uri\\file.txt";

    // Print fileName surrounded with quoutes
    System.out.printf("'%s'", fileName);

    FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(filePath);
}
```

Comment: I have googled for a while and i found that if I build a string from byte[] like`String uri  = new String(buffer)`(I receive something from datagramPacket in buffer), I will have have single quotes around the string, I don't why?